# Source.fromFile not working for HDFS file path

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

i am trying to read file contents from my hdfs for that i am using **Source.fromFile()**. It is working fine when my file is in local system but throwing error when i am trying to read file from HDFS.

```
object CheckFile{
    def main(args:Array[String]) {
        for (line <- Source.fromFile("/user/cloudera/xxxx/File").getLines()) {
            println(line)
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/quickstart.cloudera:8080/user/cloudera/xxxx/File (No such file or directory)
```

i searched but i am not able to find any solutions to this.

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Spark you should use `SparkContext` to load the files. `Source.fromFile` uses the local file system.

Say you have your `SparkContext` at `sc`,

`val fromFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://path/to/file.txt")`

Should do the trick. You might have to specify the node address, though.

UPDATE:

To add to the comment. You want to read some data from hdfs and store it as a Scala collection. This is bad practice as the file might contain milions of lines and it will crash due to insufficient amount of memory; you should use RDDs and not built-in Scala collections. Nevertheless, if this is what you want, you could do:

`val fromFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://path/to/file.txt").toLocalIterator.toArray`

Which would produce a local collection of desired type (`Array` in this case).

Comment: but i want to read my file line by line and store it in arraybuffer when i used sc.textfile() i was not getting my result thats why i switched to source.fromFile. Is there any way i can achive this ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please read-up on Spark and Hadoop infrastructure as this is a question on something that is covered in any introductory Spark course/tutorial/article.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I am looking at this right now. You must write a SCALA only program is my understanding at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

`sc.textFile("hdfs://path/to/file.txt").toLocalIterator.toArray.mkString` will give the result as  string

Comment: Code explanation will make it more acceptable and attracts more vote